# Apache - set timeout on directory navigation

Tags: php, apache, http, permissions, httpd.conf

User login to the site and and with the appropriate permissions it allows to access to page `policies/editor.php`,from this page he has a link to access to directory: `/home/account/app/Ui/policies/gray_list`.

The good: the application manages internally the session, and once the user logout or session timeout expires, the user is directed to login page.
The bad, In case the user opened a tab to the directory, i.e. `policies/gray_list/`, he can stay there beyond that expiration, so even if the user logout from the site, he still can navigate to the directory.

How can I make the session expire (I assume using apache configuration)? So actually, what I want is that once the session timeout the user will at least get the `forbidden 403 error`, like he currently gets when he tries to access this folder directly and not from `policies/editor.php`

My current configuration:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "policies/editor.php" editorpage
SetEnvIf Referer "policies/gray_list/" graylistfolder
<Directory "/home/account/app/Ui/policies/gray_list">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        IndexIgnore ..
        Order Deny,Allow 
        Deny from all 
        Allow from env=editorpage
        Allow from env=graylistfolder
</Directory>
```

Comment: How exactly is your session implemented? If we are talking about PHP sessions here – there is no “simple” connection between those and Apache default functionality. In that case, then you’re better of _disabling_ directory content listing via Apache, and use a PHP script to read the directory contents and present it to the user (either by making a PHP script the DirectoryIndex file, or by rewriting directory requests to the script) – that way, you can handle your session resp its expiry accordingly.

Comment: And relying on the referer is of course no real “protection” at all, since that value is optional as well as most easily fake-able … but you should know that already (at least I hope so).

Comment: I fully aware of the protection risks, that is acceptable with me for now. So beside the drawback of the protection on this folder I also loses the control on the session. Thanks, I think you clarified it well.

Comment: OK, then I’ll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is your session implemented? If we are talking about PHP sessions here – there is no “simple” connection between those and Apache default functionality.

In that case, then you’re better of disabling directory content listing via Apache, and use a PHP script to read the directory contents and present it to the user (either by making a PHP script the `DirectoryIndex` file, or by rewriting directory requests to the script) – that way, you can handle your session resp its expiry accordingly.

And relying on the referer is of course no real “protection” at all, since that value is optional as well as most easily fake-able.

Comment: Thanks! implemented the session control and the navigation using PHP. Actually as a programmer I prefer this solution much more. Now I have full control in the application layer :-)